# Python write without lambda

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
ch = lambda r: ("s" if r is True else ("w" if r is False else " "))
```

How can I write that without Lambda?

Comment: he general advice would be to not comporare using `is` ... but `==` - why should a value you put in here bei either True or False or something else?

Answer (score 3):

One approach could be *defining* your own *function*.

```
def ch(r):
  return "s" if r is True else ("w" if r is False else " ")
```

Answer (score 2):

Just ditch the lambda and write it as a chained ternary operator expression.

```
ch = "s" if r is True else "w" if r is False else " "
```

Also, it seems that `r` can be different data types, which seems awkward and not very robust. If you can make sure that `r` is always boolean, you can simplify this to

```
ch = "s" if r else "w"
```

but that depends on your upstream code.

Comment: `ch = "sr"[r]` would work as well

Comment: True, but that's starting to look pretty hacky. Also not bullet proof if r is indeed anything else than boolean or an integer [0,1].

Answer (score 1):

Lambdas are simply a convenience for short unnamed functions. If you're going to assign the function to a name anyway, it should probably just be a named function anyway.

```
def to_char(v):
  if v is True:
    return "s"
  elif v is False:
    return "w"
  else:
    return " "
```

It's important to note that you *can* do this inside of another function, and it'll create a local function just like `lambda` would.